# With key combinations

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

My <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>c</kbd> keys are broken, and I am trying to remap.

```
Alt + z -> x
Alt + v -> c
Alt + n -> b
```

for what I input

```
!z::x
!v::c
```

and so on but it doesn't work. I have tried initially with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> but no luck either.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where do you input `!z::x`? I have no clue what the question is actually abou, but it doesn't seem to be about programming.

Comment: This looks like AutoHotKey syntax